# iPad viewport issue with some elements and not others

Tags: ipad, viewport

I have a site (ils-main.attorneysonlinepreview.com) that scales properly for everything except the menu bar. It's a fixed width site and I've set the viewport meta tag appropriately. For some reason, the menu items are scaling up instead of down so they wrap instead of fitting as they should.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Using Chrome, I don't see any problems with scaling.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is only on the iPad, not on 'real' computers. The scaling issue is there on Chrome on the iPad as well. The menu should have 5 items, but the last two wrap and because it's white lettering on white back ground, you might not have noticed it.